# Python, Regular expression for taking a file name in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with lines that looks like this:

```
chr5    153584000   153599999   D16073_orphan_reads.fa;709[F18|R11] unkn    1   unkn    2509

chr7    153764000   153775999   D16073_orphan_reads.fa;710[F9|R21],14892_orphan_reads.fa;229[F19|R16]   unkn        1   unkn    2510

chr3    127848000   127871999   B15971_orphan_reads.fa;172[F35|R6],D16157-14_orphan_reads.fa;183[F6|R13],14892_orphan_reads.fa;229[F19|R16],USP19283_orphan_reads.fa;336[F10|R6],D15927-14_orphan_reads.fa;176[F11|R10],1007,1007   46  1007    1658

(...)
```

I want to create a Regex that takes  the fasta file (.fa) name for each line ( sometimes I have more than one file per line).

I would like to  end up with something like:

```
D16073_orphan_reads.fa

D16073_orphan_reads.fa, 14892_orphan_reads.fa

B15971_orphan_reads.fa, D1615714_orphan_reads.fa, 14892_orphan_reads.fa,USP19283_orphan_reads.fa, D15927-14_orphan_reads.fa
```

I tried:

```
 pattern= re.search(".+.[.fa]", line)
```

The problem is that the file names have very irregular names. The only clues are:

-end with .fa

-start after the comma

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `([\w-]+\.fa);` used in an [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) call will accomplish this.

```
import re

data = '''chr5    153584000   153599999   D16073_orphan_reads.fa;709[F18|R11] unkn    1   unkn    2509

chr7    153764000   153775999   D16073_orphan_reads.fa;710[F9|R21],14892_orphan_reads.fa;229[F19|R16]   unkn        1   unkn    2510

chr3    127848000   127871999   B15971_orphan_reads.fa;172[F35|R6],D16157-14_orphan_reads.fa;183[F6|R13],14892_orphan_reads.fa;229[F19|R16],USP19283_orphan_reads.fa;336[F10|R6],D15927-14_orphan_reads.fa;176[F11|R10],1007,1007   46  1007    1658
'''

for line in data.splitlines():
    filenames = re.findall('([\w|-]+\.fa);', line)
    if filenames:
        print ', '.join(filenames)
```

output:

```
D16073_orphan_reads.fa
D16073_orphan_reads.fa, 14892_orphan_reads.fa
B15971_orphan_reads.fa, D16157-14_orphan_reads.fa, 14892_orphan_reads.fa, USP19283_orphan_reads.fa, D15927-14_orphan_reads.fa
```

Comment: The `[\w|-]` character class matches a single word character (`\w`), a literal pipe `|`, or a literal hyphen `-`. I think you intended to write `[\w-]`.

Comment: @stribizhev you're right.  Thanks for the correction!  Updated the answer to remove the pipe

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `((?=\w+)[\w-]+\.fa)`

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/3

**Explanation**

`(?=\w+)` : checks to see if there are one or more words, if so, match .

`[\w-]+` : This is what is captured after, the lookahead. Either one or more word or -

`\.fa` : .fa is matched after all the conditions have been satisfied

Comment: Have a look at [what your regex will match](https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/4): `D160||||73_orphan_reads|||.fa`, `153584000fa`, etc.

Comment: stribizhev, thanks for the correction. So you mean , the lookahead or | isn't necessary?

Comment: `|` is not necessary and a dot must be escaped. At least. I do not know about the lookahead,